# How to return JSON content in Node.js Addon

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm making a Node.js extension, and I would like to return a json format object, instead of a json-formatted string.

```
#include <node.h>
#include <node_object_wrap.h>
using namespace v8;

void ListDevices(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    std::string json = "[\"test\", \"test2\"]";
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, json.c_str()));
}

void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "listDevices", ListDevices);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, InitAll)
```

How can it be done ?

```
var addon = require("./ADDON");

var jsonvar = JSON.parse(addon.listDevices());
console.log(jsonvar);
```

Actually, in this part, I would like to remove the JSON.parse

By the way, is it me, or it is really difficult to find documentation ? I tried on google, but a lot of content was out of date, and in v8.h, interesting functions weren't documented.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it (node 0.12+):

```
void ListDevices(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    // create a new object on the v8 heap (json object)
    Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);

    // set field "hello" with string "Why hello there." in that object
    obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello"), String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Why hello there."));

    // return object
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(obj);
}
```

In short, your code is returning a string `String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ...)` instead of an object `Object::New(isolate)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a JS object or array, see the [node addon docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/addons.html#addons_object_factory) (disregard the older v8 syntax since you are using node v0.11.x). Instead of creating a plain Object as in the linked example, use an [Array](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Array.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. JSON is a serialisation format. It uses strings to pass the data.
You need to parse that string to form the JS object. This **must** be done at some point.

In other words there is no such thing as a "JSON formatted object". The object you are thinking of is probably the Javascript object which is not a string and is certainly not a C++ object. The string just represents the object, and it must be converted.

Comment: @mscdex's answer makes me think that the OP is actually asking if he can create a the C++ representation of a javascript object in the V8 engine which node.js runs on.
I took the OP at his word on creating a JS object directly from JSON.